# With Continuous Instrumental variable and continuous endogenous variable, do we implicitly assume a monotonicity assumption?

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables

What is the assumption needed to interpret continuous insturmwnts with continuous endogenous variables?

If using a continuous instrument Z to capture exogenous variation in X, say we estimate a first stage coefficient that’s positive. This relationship may not be linear and may even have decreasing regions in reality, but to a first order approximation is positive. Do we just implicitly assume then a continuous version of monotonicity- I.e observations induced to change by the instrument  exposed to higher levels of Z have higher levels of X? If this is not true and the exclusion restriction still holds, then how would you interpret the coefficient in the IV?